# Is it possible to use jqmath for Android buttons?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jqmath

I have seen other posts about incorporating math formulas in Android studio with the use of WebView. However, is it possible to do the same for Buttons? If possible, how? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No. `WebView` can interpret JavaScript. `Button` cannot.